# ActiveAdmin issue with Scoped Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have the following Scope on a resource page:

```
scope("Current Active Event Registrations") { |scope| Event.current_active_event_registrations }
```

The error I keep getting when viewing the page is:

```
undefined method `except' for nil:NilClass
 c = c.except :select, :order
```

The code in `Event` looks like:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations

  scope :active_event, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :not_expired_active, -> { active_event.where('end_at > ?', DateTime.now) }

  after_save :check_for_other_active_events

  def random_winner
    self.registrations.order("RANDOM()").first
  end

  def self.current_active_event_registrations
    events = self.not_expired_active
    events.first.registrations unless events.blank?
    all if events.blank?
  end

  private
    def check_for_other_active_events
      Event.where('id != ?', self.id).update_all(active: false) if self.active
    end
end
```

I am just wanting to add in a custom scope to my Registration Resource page in my ActiveAdmin backend.

I'm using Rails 4 and the latest ActiveAdmin

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.current_active_event_registrations
  events = self.not_expired_active
  if events.blank?
    all
  else
    events.first.registrations
  end
end
```